# how to add text to span jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code that I am using to create a dynamic menu

```
function createList(test){
      alert(test);
        $('#nav')
        .append('<li class="top"><a href="nogo2" id="products" class="top_link"><span class="down"></span></a></li>');
        $('.down').text(test);
    }
```

the problem that I have is when I try to add the text to the span

```
$('.down').text(test);
```

the menu changes to whatever value is the last for example if my values are a b c d e
then all my menus e e e e e can any body help me thanks

Comment: You're setting the text to all elements with the class `.down`, not just one.

Comment: Why not just add it to your first append? `.append('blah blah <span>' + test + '</span> blah blah')`?

Comment: thank you Mohammad, but when i use append then the menu shows abcde bcde cde de e

Comment: You should append it in your .append Method only as Josh mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do it directly like this:

```
 function createList(test) {
     alert(test);
     $('#nav')
         .append('<li class="top"><a href="nogo2" id="products" class="top_link"><span class="down">' + test + '</span></a></li>');
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try using this to select only the last .down instead of all:

```
$('.down:last').text(test);
```

Answer (score 2):

The selector `$('.down')` select every elements with the class `down`

If you want to select the last created `.down` use this :

```
$('.down:last').text(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.down').each(function(){
    $(this).text(test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you're calling createList() multiple times for each menu item, but this function creates a group of li's with the same class called "down". Then, you are modifying the class (i.e. all li's that have the class "down"). What you want is to assign a unique id to each li.

here is the fiddle solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/acturbo/vZAee/2/

this should work:

```
function createList(test){
      //alert(test);
    var id = "product-" + test;
    console.log(test)

        $('#nav')
        .append('<li class="top"><a href="nogo2" id="products" class="top_link"><span id="'+ id +'"></span></a></li>');
        $("#"+id).text(test);
    }


$().ready(function() {
    createList( "a");    
    createList( "b");   
    createList( "c");   
});
```